# JSLint complaining about my try/catch

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling, try-catch, jslint

The javascript, when run through [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) yells at me and I am not sure why.

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true, evil: true, undef: true, nomen: true, eqeqeq: true, plusplus: true, bitwise: true, newcap: true, immed: true */

var foo = function() {
  try {
    console.log('foo');
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
  
  try {
    console.log('bar');
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
};

foo();
```

It tells me:

> Problem at line 12 character 11: 'e' is already defined.
>
> `} catch(e) {`

It appears to be upset that I have a second `catch(e)`.  Why would this be an issue?  Does it not simply set e to local variable inside the catch block?  Do I need to uniquely name the local variables for all trapped errors in a function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To JSLint, `try..catch` has the implicit effect of declaring `e` as a local variable. Because you have two such blocks within the same function (there is no block scope in JavaScript), JSLint sees that as **declaring a variable that has already been declared**.

Naming the variables `e1`, `e2`, *etc.* would prevent this warning from JSLint. Is it really a problem though? The ECMAScript 5 specification, section 12.14, says "No matter how control leaves the Block the LexicalEnvironment is always restored to its former state." This, in fact, does appear to be the case:

```
try {
    throw new Error("testing 1234");
} catch(fooBarBaz){
    alert("Catch: " + fooBarBaz);    // works
}

alert(fooBarBaz);    // throws exception
```

So, to conclude, this is simply a **limitation of JSLint** and is unlikely to lead to any practical problem.

Comment: It appears you are correct.  I guess that try/catch does _not_ introduce scope, as proved by this quick test I put up: http://jsfiddle.net/VRcwV/

Comment: Oh just saw the edit! So it does not introduce scope, but the local variable created by the catch statement is not available outside that catch.  So it does introduce a tiny bit of specialized scope just for that exception?

Comment: @Squeegy: IE 8 is *not* compliant, it seems. Try my test (http://jsfiddle.net/DpHMt/) in that browser, and you will see *both* alert boxes open.

Answer (score 0):

The [JSLint I use](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) shows no error at all - and logical your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a different variable, maybe its getting confused because e is usually reserved for event handlers.

Comment: as far as I know `e` is not reserved.

Answer (score 0):

JSLint might simply be wrong here. According to the ECMAScript spec, entering a `catch` block creates a new scope inside which the exception variable is defined. In your example, `e` is valid only inside the `catch` block and is not defined outside. There is no redefinition here.

Comment: ECMAScipt spec, sure.  But browser implementation, apparently not: http://jsfiddle.net/VRcwV/

Comment: @Squeegy: It's only the exception variable `e` that goes into the new scope. Variables declared with `var` are always at function scope. Try `alert(e)` and you'll see that it's undefined outside the `catch` block.

Answer (score -1):

Use a different variable for each try / catch.