# JavaScript catch clause scope

Tags: javascript

The [ECMAScript 5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.2) states the following:

> Usually a Lexical Environment is associated with some specific
>   syntactic structure of ECMAScript code such as a FunctionDeclaration,
>   a WithStatement, or a Catch clause of a TryStatement and a new Lexical
>   Environment is created each time such code is evaluated.

If my understanding is correct, then when a new Lexical Environment is created in JavaScript, a new scope is entered, which is why variables declared inside a function are not visible outside of that function:

```
function example() {
    var x = 10;
    console.log(x); //10
}
console.log(x); //ReferenceError
```

So in the above function declaration, a new Lexical Environment is created, which means `x` is not available in any outer Lexical Environments that may exist.

So the part of the quote above about Function Declarations seems to make sense. However, it also states that a new Lexical Environment is created for the Catch clause of a Try Statement:

```
try {
    console.log(y); //ReferenceError so we enter catch
} 
catch(e) {
    var x = 10;
    console.log(x); //10
}
console.log(x); //10 - but why is x in scope?
```

So how does the scope of a `catch` block work? Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a Lexical Environment is?

Comment: This SO post is somehow related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100230/javascript-catch-parameter-already-defined

Comment: Related: [Why do catch clauses have their own lexical environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15034864/1048572)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I understand it right, then what it probably means is that, in your code,

```
try {
    console.log(y); //ReferenceError so we enter catch
} 
catch(e) {
    var x = 10;
    console.log(x); //10
}
```

`e` will only exist in the catch block. Try `console.log(e);` outside the catch block and it will throw ReferenceError.

As with WithStatement, `with ({x: 1, y: 2}) { }`, x and y will only exist inside the with block.

But it doesn't mean that `var` declarations will be bound to the closest lexical environment. Actually, `var` declarations will be bound to the environment when entering an execution context.

[10.5 Declaration Binding Instantiation](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5): when the execution context in being entered, it will look for function declarations, arguments, and variable declarations and then create bindings in the execution context's VariableEnvironment.

So any variables that are declared using `var` will be accessible anywhere in the function regardless of the control structures or where it is defined inside the function. Note that this does not include nested functions as they're a separate execution context.

That means the `var` declarations will be bound to the closest execution context.

```
var x = 1;
(function() {
    x = 5; console.log(x); // 5
    if (false) { var x; }
    x = 9; console.log(x); // 9
})();
console.log(x); // 1
```

So in above code, `x = 5;` will set the `x` variable inside the inner function, because `var x;` inside `if (false) { var x; }` is bound to that function already before the function code is executed.

Comment: Ahh, this makes a lot of sense. The "So any variables that are declared using `var`..." paragraph sort of made it click. Thanks :)

Comment: Great answer and well explained

Comment: Note that even if you declare `e` at the top of the function containing the try-catch, the `e` in the `catch` block will not be the same variable. Like function parameters, it is a new variable local to the lexical context.

Comment: Netbeans (at least version 8.0.2) erroneously warns that the the error identifier in the catch clause is an undeclared global variable within the catch block.

Answer (score 10):

From [dev.opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2) (emphasis added)

> The try-catch-finally construct is fairly unique. Unlike other constructs, *it creates a new variable in the current scope* at runtime. This happens each time the catch clause is executed, where the caught exception object is assigned to a variable. This variable does not exist inside other parts of the script even inside the same scope. It is created at the start of the catch clause, then destroyed at the end of it.

So it looks like the only thing that's really within the scope of the catch is the exception itself. Other actions seem to be (or stay) bound to the outer scope of the catch (so in the example the global scope).

```
try {
    console.log(y); //ReferenceError so we enter catch
}
catch(e) {
    var x = 10;
    console.log(x); //10
}
console.log(e.message); //=> reference error
```

In [ES5](http://es5.github.com/#x12.14) these lines may be relevant (bold/emphasis added) to this:

> 1. Let ***oldEnv* be the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment**.
> 2. Let ***catchEnv*** be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing
>      oldEnv as the argument.

Also at the end of that part it states:

> NOTE: No matter how control leaves the Block *the LexicalEnvironment is
>   always restored to its former state*

Comment: Yeah I noticed that the error object was only in scope inside the `catch`. Still doesn't make sense though. I can only assume that either I still have a complete misunderstanding or (probably not surprisingly) the spec has not been followed properly. Reading section 12.14 (http://es5.github.com/#x12.14), it seems to further say that any variable declared inside the `catch` will not be in scope outside of it

Comment: I've added 2 lines from that ES5 section entitled "The production Catch ...". As far as I understand from those lines only the error is scoped locally using `catchEnv` (6-8). Other stuff gets back to `oldEnv` at the end.

Answer (score 7):

Since it was standardized in ES3, a `catch () {}` clause is (to my knowledge) the only pre-ES2015 javascript construct that creates a block-level scope, simply because it is the only block-level construct that *comes with an argument*.

It is the reason why it's been used as a polyfill by next-generation javascript transpilers to compile this:

**ES2015:**

```
{ let priv = 1; }
console.log(priv); // throws ReferenceError
```

to this:

**ES5 and lower:**

```
try { throw void 0 } catch (priv) { priv = 1 }
console.log(priv); // throws ReferenceError
```

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzling around with this question as it seemed I had already come across a similar problem, not related to the catch block in specific but within a function definition. Now I just remembered and I actually also [blogged about that problem](http://blog.js-development.com/2011/09/javascript-scoping-by-example.html) a couple of weeks ago :).

Take this code:

```
function test(){
  var x = "Hi";

  (function(){
    console.log(x);
    var x = "Hi, there!";
  })();
}
```

Code: http://jsbin.com/alimuv/2/edit#javascript,live

What's the output?? By quickly looking at it, one might assume it to be "Hi", as the scope of the variable x is taken from the function's outer scope. Instead, `undefined` is printed out. The reason is the same as for the catch block issue: **lexical scoping**, meaning that the scoping is created at *function definition* and not at run-time.

Comment: This doesn't talk about try/catch at all.